# Hero animation starting from side menu drawer and ending on destination screen in Flutter

Tags: animation, flutter, widget

I'm trying to do a Hero animation that starts from side menu drawer's item (it's Hero widget) and ends up on new screen's Hero widget. For example, on image shown below, a pie-chart icon should animate to  the final widget when destination route is shown:

[image]

Each screen contains it's own scaffold with shared drawer widget instance:

```
Scaffold(
    ...
    drawer: MyAppDrawer();
 )
```

So for each of the screens and corresponding drawer items, I have the Hero tag on the screen that equals to the side menu drawer item Hero tag.

The destination screen is replacing the current screen like so:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/");
```

After trying to push replacement screen on menu item action, instead of hero animation, I'm getting the following error:

```
There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
```

I guess it's because each of the screens already contains identical MyAppDrawer (with the same Hero tags)... But I can't omit the drawer from other screens because i need that menu to be globally accessible.

Is Hero animation from the common app side menu drawer item to destination screen Hero widget possible?
Any experiences with showing Hero animation from the drawer to the screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not sharing the drawer with all the screens you are for each screen creating a new MyAppDrawer. Thinking fast here you could create the MyAppDrawer somewhere else and import the same object onto every screen

Comment: Very strange, can you please reconfirm that all the items on the drawer have differents tags

Answer (score 0):

I have already facing this hero problem in my project.
If you put same hero tag like

```
tag:1 , tag :1, tag :1
```

then you will get this kind of error

```
tag:2 , tag:3 , tag:4
```

You will get your perfect solution through this trick.
and remembar that every hero tag must be unique in one screen.
And If you have using flotingActionButton then you have to put define tag inside button.

Answer (score 0):

```
 GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            PageRouteBuilder(
                                transitionDuration:
                                    Duration(milliseconds: 700),
                                pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => StoryInside(
                                      tag: "Story $index",
                                    ))),
                        child: Hero(
                          tag: 'Story $index',
                          child: Material(
                            animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 20),
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                'Story $index ',
                                style: style,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),


 Hero(
              tag: '${widget.tag}',
              transitionOnUserGestures: true,
              child: Text(
                '${widget.tag}',
                style: style,
              ),
            ),
```